# Modify a UI input reactively in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

Here is my example UI :

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Carry Selector"),
    sidebarPanel(
        fluidRow(
            column(6,numericInput(inputId = 'legNumbers',label = 'Number of Legs',min = 1,max=4,step=1,value=2))
        ),
        tags$hr(style="border-color: black;"),
        fluidRow(
            column(6,numericInput(inputId = 'weight1Input',label = 'Weight',min = 0,max=10,step=0.25,value=1))
        )
    ),
    mainPanel(
    )
)
```

I would like my second input to exactly mimic my first one but have no idea how to go about doing that.

Of course, my end goal is to have some other inputs react to the selection of multiple previous ones but this is the condensed version of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out :

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("TEST"),
    sidebarPanel(
        fluidRow(
            column(6,numericInput(inputId = 'legNumbers',label = 'Number of Legs',min = 1,max=4,step=1,value=2))
        ),
        tags$hr(style="border-color: black;"),
        uiOutput("ui_test")
    ),
    mainPanel(
    )
)


server <- function(input,output){
    output$ui_test <- renderUI({
        fluidRow(
            column(6,numericInput(inputId = 'weight1Input',label = 'Weight',min = 0,max=10,step=0.25,value=input$legNumbers))
        )
    })  
}
```